Assign a particular column value to a stage variable in Datastage
Column1  column2
abc      10
efg      20
ijk      30
efg      20

If column 1 ='efg' then assign column2 as value of column2 where column1 ='abc'

Expected output:
Column1  column2
abc      10
efg      10
ijk      30
efg      10

I tried to assign column2 value (when column1 ='ABC') in a stage variable. Then if column 1 ='efg' then use the from stage variable  but it is not working.
